# Has this difference equation :$x_{n+1}=Ax^2_{n}-Bx^2_{n-1}$ been studied before?

Tags: reference-request, recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems

I posted [this](//mathoverflow.net/q/209452/75050) problem before in MO but only I would like to know if this  difference equation :$$x_{n+1}=Ax^2_{n}-Bx^2_{n-1}$$
where $A(\theta)= \cos(\theta)$ and $B(\theta) =\sin(\theta)$  are nonnegative parameters and $x_{-1}$, $x_0$ are nonnegative initial conditions with $x_{-1}+x_{0}>0$  was studied before (Global behavior and  boundedness of its solutions).

Are there any references or books discussing it?

Comment: have you looked at behavior for any base cases yet? e.g. $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$, etc

Comment: pleas see the answer in :http://mathoverflow.net/q/209452/75050, represented picture